# PCF8563 does not remember time when restarting Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, time, datalogging

I'm trying to use the following RTC module (PCF8563) with Arduino Uno.[image]

I am using [this library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RTC-PCF8563) to set/get time and date from PCF8563. However, whenever I shut down the Arduino, the time/date is lost! Even though, as you can see in the picture, the module is equipped with a 3V battery to keep running when Arduino is unplugged.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to put the jumper in the “BAT” position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

The solution is simply to put a jumper between BAT and VCC positions in the module itself. Many thanks to [Edgar Bonet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/7508/edgar-bonet)